# How do I set a Main Menu Scene to my game? QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm totally new to QT and C++. I followed an online tutorial and created my first game using QT. The game is basically like this. I'm a tank and I can move the tank to Left and Right on the bottom corner of the scene. Bombs are falling randomly from the Topside of the scene to the ground. I can shoot at them by pressing the spacebar. when the bullet hits the bomb, the score is being counted...

My game has only one scene. When I run the program, the game starts at that time itself. I want my program to open a **Main Menu** first when I run the game. The Main Menu should contain two QPushButtons. They are **Start Game** & **Exit**. I don't know how to implement that part.

**Game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include "Score.h"
#include "Health.h"
#include "Player.h"


class Game: public QGraphicsView{
public:
    Game(QWidget * parent=0);

    QGraphicsScene * scene;
    Player * player;
    Score * score;
    Health * health;
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Health.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QGraphicsTextItem>
#include <QFont>
#include "Enemy.h"
#include <QMediaPlayer>


Game::Game(QWidget *parent){
    // create the scene
    scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    scene->setSceneRect(0,0,800,600); // make the scene 800x600 instead of infinity by infinity (default)

    //Set the Background
    setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(QImage(":/images/background.jpg")));

    // make the newly created scene the scene to visualize (since Game is a QGraphicsView Widget,
    // it can be used to visualize scenes)
    setScene(scene);
    setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    setFixedSize(800,600);

    // create the player
    player = new Player();
     // change the rect from 0x0 (default) to 100x100 pixels
    player->setPos(400,500); // TODO generalize to always be in the middle bottom of screen
    // make the player focusable and set it to be the current focus
    player->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
    player->setFocus();
    // add the player to the scene
    scene->addItem(player);

    // create the score/health
    score = new Score();
    scene->addItem(score);
    health = new Health();
    health->setPos(health->x(),health->y()+25);
    scene->addItem(health);

    // spawn enemies
    QTimer * timer = new QTimer();
    QObject::connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),player,SLOT(spawn()));
    timer->start(2000);

    //Playing the Background Music
    QMediaPlayer * music = new QMediaPlayer();
    music->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/bgmusic.mp3"));
    music->play();
    show();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "Game.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>

Game * game;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    game = new Game();
    game->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One straightforward way to do it would be to create a `GameMenu` class that subclasses [QGraphicsRectObject](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html), using the same approach you currently use to create the other in-game objects like `Player`, `Score`, and `Health`, except that the `GameMenu` object would be drawn as a rectangle (or whatever) and have the appropriate menu-text-options drawn into it (as part of the subclasses [paint](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qgraphicsrectitem.html#paint) method).  Then you'd just place the `GameMenu` object into the center of your QGraphicsScene.  You'd also need to add conditional logic to your code so that the gameplay behaves differently when the `GameMenu` object is visible (i.e. don't spawn enemy tanks while the GameMenu is visible, and handle arrow-key presses to update the GameMenu object's selected-option rather than to move the player's tank).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir! Could you please tell me how to do it? I have absolutely no idea how to do it... I'd really appreciate it if you can...

Comment: I won't write your code for you -- the description I wrote above should be sufficient for you to write it yourself.  My suggestion is to start by copying a part of your program that already works, e.g. make a copy of your `Health` class, rename it to `GameMenu`, and then start incrementally modifying its functionality away from displaying a health-meter and towards displaying a game-menu, recompiling and testing as you go along to see how the program's behavior changes as you modify the code.  The initial baby-steps will give you the confidence to make further modifications as you go.